# MS Edge - restore deleted favorites folder

Tags: microsoft-edge

I keep my favorites in different folders. I have accidently deleted one of my folders. Is there any chance to restore it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there seems to impossible to restore deleted favorites folder.

However, you can find some useful tips in [this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/deleted-favorites-from-edge-by-accident/315145a5-fb5f-4ef8-a0af-711fb41046ea). You can refer to Firedog's reply in the link, but that will only work if the bookmarks backup was created before your accidental deletion.

Comment: Hi @Mark I have not heard from you for a couple of days. Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.